# How to check if a value has been a result of a sanitize function at compile time

Tags: typescript

I want the parameters of a function to be a result of a sanitize function, how can I enforce that at compile time.

```
function sanitize<A>(a: A): A {
    return a;
}

function useGoodA<A>(a: A): void {
    // make sure a has seen a call to sanitize
    console.log(a);
}

let a = [1,2,3];

useGoodA(a) // I want compiler error

useGoodA(sanitize(a)) // I want this to work
```

I don't want to introduce extra types into my function signatures, but that's necessary I guess.

### Edit

What if function doesn't accept type parameters:

```
type Board = [number, number]

function useSanitizedBoard(b: Board): void {
    console.log(b);
}

useSanitizedBoard([1,1]) // throws
useSanitizedBoard(sanitize([1,1])); // ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the trick that enums are nominally typed, which means you can add a sanitization flag without changing the structure of your code at all:

```js
// declare enum so it doesn't actually generate extra code
declare enum Sanitized {}

function sanitize<A>(a: A): A & Sanitized {
    // cast here to assert it's sanitized
    return a as A & Sanitized;
}

// alternatively function useGood<A>(a: A & Sanitized): void
function useGoodA<A extends Sanitized>(a: A): void {
    // make sure a has seen a call to sanitize
    console.log(a);
}

let a = [1,2,3];

useGoodA(a); // this errors

useGoodA(sanitize(a)); // this works

// sanitized value can also be downcast to original type
const x: number = sanitize(5);
// or you can maintain the sanitized state
// (this is also what type inference will do)
const y: number & Sanitized = sanitize(5);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=43#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlSQHYFcC2oDOB7UASwBcJ9Jc0ByM+aEjeWWAT1AHN1JF4SVIADxK9Q0fFABQUOEgGYcAZXhpSRAF6RwoAN4BfSZIBmGNAyL40eFWs0AeAIIA+ABTwAXKAcBKTw9AAZKDKqiQaWrqSoNGgIGLwuGQAFjwoJIQJuDxkpNS41qHh4FExyIyIVvCgCV6BwTZhmuAA3JIGknHM-BV8RABukGygJmZhlqAYWQDi+BKOrh61QSG2Wr6gffhExSPm45OQMxIOjqjC6OD5K41aC37rm9uRMbFgWPAA1ii4GMjVoEkall0P9oMxYKB0gVViVouI0ARYJAAHSwfAcNzeVrtJF0UAAXlAAG0AIwAGgATGSAMwAXVakgOR3ADkxzVekKSRHyPEQ+EQuEMTNmLJcuAa4UxWI5JC5+QA7vyPoKOmBxYUmhtmBgUGDKrACKAAEYocD4eVmBJkKH8ogcIhoZiQ1gAB0gknhiVAgk8ChNiAJ0JuLgArFjVaB+aBWPgMPErO8HSR4A7Od8JZrEnx3XEXLLucR8sxDfLAdbXSgHUZUmYUPKiCxyN4PZYvaxfdh-XVrkVA+rVqGsUA)

Comment: What if the function doesn't accept type parameters? I edited my question to show.

Comment: @eguneys You'd modify the alternative syntax, so `useSanitizedBoard(b: Board & Sanitized)`